# How to check if characters in a string are alphabetically ordered

Tags: python, string

I have been trying these code but there is something wrong. I simply want to know if the first string is alphabetical.

```
def alp(s1):
    s2=sorted(s1)
    if s2 is s1:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

This always prints False and when i say print s1 or s2, it says "NameError: name 's1' is not defined"

Comment: On which line do you get this error?

Comment: Print s1 - This the line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`is` is identity testing which compares the object IDs, `==` is the equality testing:

```
In [1]: s1 = "Hello World"
In [2]: s2 = "Hello World"

In [3]: s1 == s2
Out[3]: True

In [4]: s1 is s2
Out[4]: False
```

Also note that `sorted` returns a list, so change it to:

```
if ''.join(s2) == s1:
```

Or

```
if ''.join(sorted(s2)) == s1:
```

Comment: Nothing is changed the same result

Comment: @billwild maybe the string is not sorted :)

Comment: It might not be the fastest, but it reads quite nicely, and I would not like to encounter a string so lengthy that sorting becomes a problem.

Comment: @tvdien I was going to propose a faster way, but saw the problems in the OP's question and decided to address those instead. I did however, upvote the faster solution :)

Answer (score 4):

I would do it using `iter` to nicely get the previous element:

```
def is_ordered(ss):
   ss_iterable = iter(ss)
   try:
       current_item = next(ss_iterable)
   except StopIteration:
       #replace next line to handle the empty string case as desired.
       #This is how *I* would do it, but others would prefer `return True`
       #as indicated in the comments :)
       #I suppose the question is "Is an empty sequence ordered or not?"
       raise ValueError("Undefined result.  Cannot accept empty iterable")

   for next_item in ss_iterable:
       if next_item < current_item:
           return False
       current_item = next_item
   return True
```

This answer has complexity O(n) in the absolute worst case as opposed to the answers which rely on `sort` which is O(nlogn).

Comment: @tvdien -- It does read a little strange.  I'll happily accept proposals for better variable names :)

Comment: I improved the readability and accounted for the case of an empty sequence.

Comment: @tvdien -- I liked the edit, but I don't think that the case of an empty sequence should be accounted for since I don't think there is any reasonable default behavior to have.  I suppose maybe raising a `ValueError` would be appropriate, but I didn't like having `pass` in there (effectively returning `None`) which would behave like `False` in a conditinal test where this is likely to be used ...

Comment: If being ordered means that every second element is no lower than the first, an empty sequence is perfectly ordered. All other solutions also indicate this. BTW, try-except-else is Python idiom.

Comment: @tvdien -- That definition of ordering doesn't work because there *is no first element*.  OP can switch out my `raise` with `return True` if desired though and I think the func is still OK.  Also, I know about `try-except-else-finally`, but there's no need for `else` here.  We leave the block when we `raise ValueError` (or `return`).  I don't like increasing my indentation level unnecessarily.  Technically I could put the `return True` on an `else` on the `for` loop as well, but it doesn't make a difference and I think the code is easier to read without it.  (but that's my opinion).

Comment: @thg435 -- What do you mean `partial ordering`?  This only checks whether OP's string is already ordered or not -- It doesn't actually do any ordering itself.

Comment: @mgilson: yes, you're right. I was thinking your code only works for partially ordered sets, since it compares pairs of elements, but on a second thought it also requires the set to be totally ordered, due to transitivity. However, when a comparison is intransitive (as in `paper < scissors < rock` where `<` is `beats`), this method cannot be applied.

Comment: @thg435 -- That's a fair point, although in that case the built in `sorted` would probably not be too happy either...

Answer (score 4):

You could see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3755251/451980) and use something which works for any sequence:

```
all(s1[i] <= s1[i+1] for i in xrange(len(s1) - 1))
```

Example:

```
>>> def alp(s1):
...     return all(s1[i] <= s1[i+1] for i in xrange(len(s1) - 1))
...
>>> alp("test")
False
>>> alp("abcd")
True
```

Comment: This works since strings are indexible.  It wouldn't work on arbitrary iterables however:  `iter('foobar')`.  That aside, I think this is a great answer -- Much better than sorting.  +1

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are comparing strings with strings:

```
In [8]: s = 'abcdef'

In [9]: s == ''.join(sorted(s))
Out[9]: True

In [10]: s2 = 'zxyw'

In [11]: s2 == ''.join(sorted(s2))
Out[11]: False
```

If `s1` or `s2` is a string, `sorted` will return a list, and you will then be comparing a string to a list. In order to do the comparison you want, using `''.join()` will take the list and join all the elements together, essentially creating a string representing the sorted elements.

Comment: @billwild Because we are comparing `zxyw` and `wxyz`, and since `s2` is not alphabetical (i.e. equal to `wxyz`), we get False

Answer (score 2):

use something like this:

`sorted()` returns a list and you're trying to compare a list to a string, so change that list to a string first:

```
In [21]: "abcd"=="".join(sorted("abcd"))
Out[21]: True

In [22]: "qwerty"=="".join(sorted("qwerty"))
Out[22]: False

#comparsion of list and a string is False
In [25]: "abcd"==sorted("abcd")
Out[25]: False
```