# How can I make a code that determines if a list is sorted or not in Python?

Tags: python, list, sorting

How would I write a function that takes a list as an argument and verifies whether or not the list is sorted?

I want it to return true if sorted and false otherwise. For example:

```
>>> is_sorted([1, 5, 8, 10]) 
True

>>> is_sorted([4, 1, 7, 8])
False
```

However, I'm unsure of how to do this with any kind of list at all

Comment: What language are you wanting the function for?

Comment: Please show us what you have attempted.Are there any performance or space req.it all depends on the list size,the type of list

Comment: @JasonW I'm using Python

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755136/pythonic-way-to-check-if-a-list-is-sorted-or-not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest version that gets O(n) performance:

```
def is_sorted(lst):
    return all(a <= b for a,b in zip(lst, lst[1:]))
```

Comment: I would suggest using `izip` and possibly `islice` from `itertools` though.

Answer (score 1):

An obvious way is to sort it and compare for equality with the original list:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def is_sorted(mylist):
    testlist = sorted(mylist[:])
    return testlist == mylist

print is_sorted([1, 4, 6, 7])
print is_sorted([1, 7, 6, 5])
```

outputs:

```
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox$ ./sorted.py
True
False
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox$
```

If you want something slightly more efficient (presuming you want to check if it's sorted in ascending order):

```
def is_sorted(mylist):
    last_item = mylist[0]

    for item in mylist:
        if item < last_item:
            return False
        last_item = item

    return True
```

Comment: Yes, that's the easy way. Also slow: O(n log n) rather than O(n).

Answer (score 0):

This should be a O(n) solution by iterating through the list to check for values out of order. O(n) is worst case since it returns false the first element it finds out of order.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def is_sorted(mylist):
    for i, val in enumerate(mylist):
        if (i > 0 and mylist[i] < mylist[i-1]):
            return False
    return True

print is_sorted([1, 4, 6, 7])
print is_sorted([1, 7, 6, 5])
```

Output:

```
True
False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_sorted(mylist):
    return False not in [sorted(mylist)[idx] == val for idx, val in enumerate(mylist)]

>>> is_sorted([1, 2, 3, 4])
True

>>> is_sorted([1, 2, 4, 3])
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the most simplest way to do this:

```
def is_sorted(l):
    return True if l == sorted(l) else False
```