# Sorting variable number of columns/rows

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

```
users_grpd = pairs.groupByKey()

users_grpd_flattened = users_grpd.map(
    lambda (k, vals): "{0} {1}".format(k, ' '.join(str(x) for x in vals)))
```

the first column in `userid` and the rest of the columns are product ids. I would now like to sort the product ids per user. The number of products per user are not fixed, but will vary. Here is how `users_grpd_flattened` looks like: Is there a way to efficiently sort the product ids/user?

```
userid   product ids.............

30095212 208518 10519 208520 120821
3072220 20506 205037
209212 208518 10519 208520 120821
100222 20506 205037 10519 208520 120821 20116  124574 102575
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`mapValues`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.mapValues) with [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted).

```
users_grpd.mapValues(sorted)
```

When you use `mapValues` input partitioning is preserved so there is no shuffling involved and the most expensive and potentially dangerous operation is preceding `groupByKey`.

Check if everything works as expected (`is_sorted` taken from [@WaiYipTung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229075/wai-yip-tung) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3755251/1560062)):

```
def is_sorted(l):
    return all(l[i] <= l[i+1] for i in xrange(len(l)-1))

pairs = sc.parallelize([
    (30095212, 208518), (30095212, 10519), (30095212, 208520), 
    (30095212, 120821), (3072220, 20506), (3072220, 205037),
    (209212, 208518), (209212, 10519), (209212, 208520), (209212, 120821),
    (100222, 20506), (100222, 205037), (100222, 10519), (100222, 208520),
    (100222, 120821), (100222, 20116), (100222, 124574), (100222, 102575),
    (87620, 12012851), (87620, 12022661), (87620, 12033827), (87620, 1205376)
])

users_grpd_with_sorted_vals = pairs.groupByKey().mapValues(sorted)
```

Some checks

```
>>> all(users_grpd_with_sorted_vals.values().map(is_sorted).collect())
True
>>> users_grpd_with_sorted_vals.lookup(87620)
[[1205376, 12012851, 12022661, 12033827]]
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any recommended way for avoiding groupByKey? Basically I need to group

users_projected = sqlContext.sql("SELECT user, prod_ids FROM infotable")

pairs = distinct_users_projected.map(lambda x: (x.user, x.prod_ids))

users_grpd = pairs.groupByKey()

Comment: If `groupByKey` is followed by some kind of reduce operations which reduces size of the data you should consider using `reduceByKey`, `combineByKey` or `aggregateByKey` (you can read more [here](http://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html)), but here there is nothing to gain by that. If output specification is not fixed an alternative is to simple partition by key, sort, and output (`userid`, `product_id`) pairs.

Comment: Unfortunately, users_grpd.mapValues(sorted) is not working. For example, here is a row after that operation.

100876220 12012850 12022660 12033837 1205366

Comment: What does it mean "not working"? If there is some issue please provide an example input and expected output.

Comment: If you look at the o/p that I just sent:

User id Product ids
87620 12012851 12022661 12033827 1205376
The product ids (should be sorted, but are not.)

Comment: Looks of for me. Please take a look a the example, I've added to the answer.

Comment: I am glad to hear that. If it solved your problem please accept the answer :)