# Finding Incrementing value from list

Tags: python

I got two question?

- I need to check whether a[0] greater than a[1] and so on till a[n]
- I need to check Whether a[n] lesser than a[n-1] and so on till a[0]

For Example, values in list:

```
['0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '7.79', '-1.63', '-0.37', '-1.42', '-0.20', '0.16', '0.25']
```

Comment: what is the output you would like to see? what have you tried? please show the code of what you have tried or you are very unlikely to get an answer here.

Comment: I've tried to check by comparing a[0] to a[1], then a[1] to a[2] manually. Recursive function will be great.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755136/pythonic-way-to-check-if-a-list-is-sorted-or-not may help

Comment: Are you saying it needs to be sorted in reverse order, or just that the first value is the maximum and the last value the minimum?

Comment: In case 1, 1st value should be lesser compared to others. In case 2, reverse the list and first value should be higher compared to others

Comment: I just wanted to say. All value are increment in nature.

Comment: Can you rephrase the question as: "Are the value numerically sorted?" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try something like this: iterate simultaneously over

- `x[:-1]`: the list without the last element
- `x[1:]`: the list without the first element

and compare the values. note that for equality you can compare the list elements as strings - but for `<` and `>` you probably want to convert them to `float` before comparing.

```
x=['0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '7.79', '-1.63', 
   '-0.37', '-1.42', '-0.20', '0.16', '0.25']

for xj, xi in zip(x[:-1], x[1:]):

    if xj == xi:
        print '{} == {}'.format(xj, xi)
    elif float(xj) < float(xi):
        print '{} < {}'.format(xj, xi)
    else:
        print '{} > {}'.format(xj, xi)
```

output:

```
0.00 == 0.00
0.00 == 0.00
0.00 < 7.79
7.79 > -1.63
-1.63 < -0.37
-0.37 > -1.42
-1.42 < -0.20
-0.20 < 0.16
0.16 < 0.25
```

---

**UPDATE:**

after your comment it semst that you just want a list containing string telling you if the elements increase or not. this should work:

```
def comp_str(xj, xi):
    if xj == xi:
        return 'equal'
    elif float(xj) < float(xi):
        return 'yes'
    else:
        return 'no'

compare = [ comp_str(xj, xi) for xj, xi in zip(x[:-1], x[1:]) ]
print compare

# -> ['equal', 'equal', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes']
```

Comment: I've done something like this `temp[:] = []#Emptying the list
    for i in range(len(list)):
        if i < len(list)-1:
            if list[i] > list[i+1]:
                #print "Yes"
                temp.append("Yes")
            if list[i] == list[i+1]:
                #print "Equal"
                temp.append("Equal")
            else:
                #print "no"
                temp.append("No")
    if "No" in temp:
        print "Decrement Value available"
    else:
        print "Increment Values only"`

Answer (score 0):

```
x=['0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '7.79', '-1.63', '-0.37', '-1.42', '-0.20', '0.16', '0.25']
y=zip(x,x[1:])

print [(i,j) for i,j in enumerate(y) if j[0]>j[1]]
```

You can use `zip` and `enumerate` to achieve the same.

For second part you can use

```
x=['0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '7.79', '-1.63', '-0.37', '-1.42', '-0.20', '0.16', '0.25']
x=x[::-1]
y=zip(x,x[1:])

print [(i,j) for i,j in enumerate(y) if j[0]<j[1]]
```

Comment: I've tried your 1st part of code, and last two value are not display. If every value is greater than, printing out like "Increment" can be good.

Comment: I'm trying something like this `for i in range(len(list)):
        if i < len(list)-1:
            if list[i] > list[i+1]:
                print "Yes"
            if list[i] == list[i+1]:
                print "Equal"
            else:
                print "no"`

Comment: If all value are increment in nature, just printing out "Increment" will be good.

Comment: @jOSe instead of (i,j) use "increased"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89034/discussion-between-jose-and-vks).

Comment: @jOSe  `print ["increment" for i,j in enumerate(y) if j[0]>j[1]]`