# How to check if a list of dictionaries is sorted?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have created a list of dictionaries:

```
l = []
d = {"a":1,"b",2}
l.append(d)
d = {"a":5,"b":6}
l.append(d)
d = {"a":3,"b":4}
l.append(d)
```

Now, how do I check whether the list of dictionaries is sorted or not based on the key `a` or key `b`?

Comment: Can you explain what makes a list of dictionaries “sorted” by your definition? I don't think this is a well-defined property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the default check if something is sorted, but index before comparing:

```
k = "a"
all(l[i][k] <= l[i+1][k] for i in range(len(l) - 1))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
print(l == sorted(l, key=lambda d:d["a"]))
False
```

Comment: This is O(n log n) _at best_, while my answer is O(1) at best, and O(n) at worst.

Comment: yes. this just an intuitive solution. when performance matters, one can always try something more optimized like yours.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755136/pythonic-way-to-check-if-a-list-is-sorted-or-not), you can efficiently check if a list is sorted using:

```
all(l[i] <= l[i+1] for i in xrange(len(l)-1))
```

To support a custom key, you can define something like

```
def is_sorted(iterable, key=None):
    if key is None:
        key = lambda x : x
    return all(key(iterable[i]) <= key(iterable[i+1]) for i in xrange(len(iterable)-1))
```

In this case, you can just use a simple lambda function looking up the dictionary values as the key (assuming all elements are dicts containing `a` and `b`), e.g.

```
# Check if list of dictionaries are sorted by value of 'a'
>>> is_sorted(l, key=lambda x: x["a"])

# Check if list of dictionaries are sorted by value of 'b'
>>> is_sorted(l, key=lambda x: x["b"])

# Check if list of dictionaries are sorted by value of 'a', then 'b'
>>> is_sorted(l, key=lambda x: (x["a"], x["b"]))
```