# Ascending Order in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to get this code to associate True with the variable is_ascending if the list numbers is in ascending order and False if otherwise

```
for i in range(2, len(numbers)) :
if numbers[i] < numbers[i-1] :
    is_ascending = False
    break
else :
    is_ascending = True
```

But the program im doing, this is for a class, says this won't work. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your indentation isn't quite correct. Have you tested the code on a test list of `numbers`?

Comment: You should use `range(1, len(numbers))` because 1 means the second element and 0 index would refer to the first element. That being said, there are indentation errors in your code as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if sorted(numbers) == numbers:
    is_ascending = True
```

That'll do it.

Comment: I added an else statement but besides for that, it worked. Thank you!

Comment: you could even do a one liner : `is_ascending = sorted(numbers) == numbers`.

Comment: This does work and looks nice, but is much less efficient as you don't break when an element is reached. It is at best O(n) instead of O(1)

Answer (score 2):

You should use `range(1, len(numbers))` as `1` means the second element and `0` index would refer to the first element. Besides that, your `if-else` statements should be inside the `for` loop (indentation issue). Your code works as below for a unsorted list and also for a sorted list. Try running it with 
`numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]` and it will print `True`

```
numbers = [1,2,4,3,5]

for i in range(1, len(numbers)):
    if numbers[i] < numbers[i-1]:
        is_ascending = False
        break
    else:
        is_ascending = True

print (is_ascending)        
> False
```

Answer (score 2):

Bazingaa's answer is good and more readable to people not as familiar with functional programming. There's still two things you could improve on.

- You could iterate over `range(len(numbers) - 1)` and compare each element with the next one instead of the previous. It's a personal preference but I find it more intuitive than the two-parameter notation of `range`.
- You could use the `all` function as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3755251/2813263

It would give you something like this:

```
is_ascending = all(numbers[i] <= numbers[i+1] for i in range(len(numbers) - 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you build a list of the outcome of the paired comparisons:

```
numbers = [10,20,30,40,20,50]
outcomes = [ numbers[i] > numbers[i-1] for i in range(1,len(numbers))]
print(outcomes)
```

This outputs:

```
[True, True, True, False, True]
```

The False is for the 40 & 20 comparison.

Then you can use all() to determine if the list is in ascending order

```
numbers = [10,20,30,40,50,60]
is_ascending = all([ numbers[i] > numbers[i-1] for i in range(1,len(numbers)) ])
print(is_ascending) # prints True
numbers = [10,5,20,30,40,50,60]
is_ascending = all([ numbers[i] > numbers[i-1] for i in range(1,len(numbers)) ])
print(is_ascending) # prints False
```

Comment: We must have posted at the same time. Note that you can drop the square brackets, which will turn the list comprehension into a generator. Instead of creating a list and then checking all elements, it will iterate over the loop and stop as soon as an incorrect value is found.

Comment: Yes, we must have been typing at the same time. Thanks for pointing out about dropping the []. A good tip.