# Determine if the sequence is incremented? (python)

Tags: python

```
def isIncreasing(seq):
    flag = True
    for i in range(len(seq) - 1):
        if seq[i + 1] < seq [i]:
            flag = False
    return flag


a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  # print True
b = [2, 3, 1, 5, 4]  # print False
```

I have two sequence.
Is there any better way to modify my function if the sequence is incrementing?

Comment: You could return False directly from your `if` block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning as soon as you find one is better. You can leverage [pythons built in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) to do that:

```
def isIncreasing(seq):
   return all(a<b for a,b in zip(seq,seq[1:]))
```

This zippes your sequence into pairs:

```
[1,2,3,4] => [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)]
```

and checks each pair. `all()` terminates as soon as it finds a `False`.

**Documentation**:

- [all()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all)
- [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a one liner:

```
all(seq[i] < seq[i+1] for i in range(len(seq)-1))
```

Credits: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3755251/3442256)

Answer (score 1):

Using [numpy.diff()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.9.2/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) and `all()`

```
In [33]: all(i>=1 for i in np.diff(b))
Out[33]: False

In [34]: all(i>=1 for i in np.diff(a))
Out[34]: True
```