# Check if list is sorted in either ascending or descending order in one pass

Tags: python, sorting, time-complexity

Is there a way to check if a list is sorted either in ascending or descending order in one pass?

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3755410/15070470), I modified to also support descending order check, so my code now looks like this, is there a way to check this without having to use two for loops?

```
def is_sorted(check):
    current = check
    forwarded = check[1:]
    ascending_check = all(i<=j for i, j in zip(current, forwarded))
    descending_check = all(i>=j for i, j in zip(current, forwarded))
    return ascending_check or descending_check

numbers = list(range(1, 10))
print(is_sorted(numbers))
reverse_numbers = list(range(10, 0, -1))
print(is_sorted(reverse_numbers))
not_sorted = [1, 3, 2, 4, 5]
print(is_sorted(not_sorted))
```

Comment: The for-loop is running in O(n) so two for-loop is running in O(2 * n) which is not really that bad as you are still having linear time-complexity.

Comment: @Quizzarex thanks for replying, I submitted this and I did not get the total marks, the reason was there is solution where only one for loop is needed

Comment: Check out this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3755251/2570277

Comment: @Nick maybe I am not picking this up, but aren't I doing the same thing? `l[i] <= l[i+1]` would only check ascending so I still have to check descending don't I?

Comment: @Lorena It is only testing ascending order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check pairs of consecutive elements, keep track of whether the first pair that is not `==` is `<` or `>`, and check that all the other pairs have the same relation (if not equal):

```
def is_sorted(lst):
    asc = None
    for i in range(len(lst)-1):
        a, b = lst[i], lst[i+1]
        if a == b:
            continue
        if asc is None:
            asc = (a < b)
        if (a < b) != asc:
            return False
    return True
```

That's a bit verbose, but you could also make it shorter with `next` and `all`, using a shared `zip` iterator for both so the entire list is iterated only once.

```
def is_sorted(lst):
    pairs = zip(lst, lst[1:])
    asc = next((a < b for a, b in pairs if a != b), None)
    return asc is None or all((a < b) == asc for a, b in pairs if a != b)
```

However, this version (like your original) will create a copy of the input list with `lst[1:]`, so that's not really just a single loop, either. To fix that, you could e.g. use `itertools.tee` or `islice`.

Comment: No need for `asc is None or `.

Comment: @superbrain Hm, good point... the `all` would still work as it would be `all` on an empty iterator due to `if a != b`... still I'd rather leave it in, it's a bit clearer that way IMHO.

Comment: Maybe. Although for clarity it might also be beneficial to not almost-repeat the generator. [Fun version](https://tio.run/##bU5tSgMxEP2/p3j@SyBK1ypIsVfwAqWELDvRwHYSJ2mpXn6d1qKgHYbhwfua8tHeMi@fiszzSBGp@pql0Wim2uyqg86YYqxYwwQ8Y0DMguAUJMZnKiehg55Nv9papIiAmzUGe/YKtb0wwjSZXSiG6djMOc/hJTPZO@/p3Xv3XWJt1/F@N5Cc@qZUm5HAr2R6h36hbJHEzfw@eRErI3RQQP66feGge9tfifhjVAXndiE1ZaPVS4d7hweHx@3/D37E6pznLw).

Comment: Could also dump the `(a < b ... if a != b)` generator into the `all_equal` [recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes), although that one is surprisingly complicated :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can examine the first two elements, then return `True` if the entire list has the same ordering as those two. You have to also take into account the possibility that there is a tie at the beginning, and that the entire list only contains the same values throughout.

```py
def is_sorted(check):
    ascending = True
    descending = True
    previous = check[0]
    for item in check[1:]:
        if ascending and item < previous:
            ascending = False
        if descending and item > previous:
            descending = False
        if not ascending and not descending:
            return False
        previous = item
    return True
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/YjBB9T

Comment: As it seems like the method `is_sorted` is just asking if the array is sorted in either ascending or descending order, then I would `return ascending or descending`.

Comment: @Quizzarex Thanks, I had misread the OP's code slightly.

Answer (score 2):

This would work:

```
def is_sorted(check):
    asc = desc = True
    i, L = 0, len(check)
    while (i < (L-1)) and (asc or desc):
        if check[i] < check[i+1]:
            desc = False
        elif check[i] > check[i+1]:
            asc = False
        if not (asc or desc):
            break
        i += 1
    if asc and desc:
        return "Ascending and Descending"
    elif asc:
        return "Ascending"
    elif desc:
        return "Descending"
    else:
        return "Not ascending and not descending"
```

**Tests:**

```
print (is_sorted([1, 2, 3]))
print (is_sorted([3, 2, 1]))
print (is_sorted([1, 2, 3, 2, 1]))
print (is_sorted([1, 1, 1]))
```

**Output:**

```
Ascending
Descending
Not ascending and not descending
Ascending and Descending
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to check if sorted ascending way, if not: `array[::-1]`, and check again.
`array[::-1]` reverses the array.

Comment: Doesn't this require two loops as well?

Comment: this is still two pass, I was told a one pass solution exists

Comment: It's 3 passes, not 2. The expression `array[::-1]` itself triggers a (reversed) copy operation, and creating that copy counts as one pass (the second pass). Then, you pass this (reversed) copy to your function, which makes one more pass (the third pass)