# list comparasion based on a weak order of a sequence

Tags: python, list, compare

I'm trying to figure out a way to check if order exists in a sequence of elements.
For example:

```
orderExists = [
    ['a','c','d','e'],['b','d','f'],['a','b','c','e']
]
orderViolation = [
    ['a','c','d','e'],['b','d','f'],['a','e','c','b']
]
```

Order exists because the valid sequence should look like `a,b,c,d,e,f`.
**In sublists the elements may be absent**.
For example in `orderExists[0] = ['a','c','d','e']`    `b` and `f` are absent but as long as `c` comes after `a` and is before `d` order is respected.

Order is violated because in `orderViolation[2] = ['a','e','c','b']` `e` should not be before `c`.

Also this is a test case, i don't know the valid sequence, the only thing that i have is a list of sublists as in the example above.

Is there any effective way to find out if there order exists or not?

NOTE: The sublists do not contain only elements in alphabetical order.

For Example: New York --> Los Angeles --> Chicago

```
orderExists = [
        ['Los Angeles', 'Chicago'],
        ['New York','Los Angeles'],
        ['New York','Chicacgo']
    ]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pythonic way to check if a list is sorted or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755136/pythonic-way-to-check-if-a-list-is-sorted-or-not)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a masking list that contains whether  the lists inside the lists are ordered or not, by comparing each inner list with their sorted version.

```py
>>> [x==sorted(x) for x in orderExists]
[True, True, True]

>>> [x==sorted(x) for x in orderViolation]
[True, True, False]
```

Or, you can just compare if each item is greater than the previous inside each sub-lists:

```py
>>> [all(x[i+1]>x[i] for i in range(len(x)-1)) for x in orderViolation]
[True, True, False]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

This solution is great for the test case that i provided, but if i have a list of cities and each sublist is a version of order in which they were visited.

For example:

New York --> Los Angeles --> Chicago

`orderExists = [
    ['Los Angeles', 'Chicago'],
    ['New York','Los Angeles'],
    ['New York','Chicacgo']
]`

Comment: @alcheringa Please edit your question and include test cases representative of your actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
import itertools

def compareOrders(l1, l2):
    
    aa = [elem for elem in l1 if elem in l2]
    bb = [elem for elem in l2 if elem in l1]

    return aa == bb


orderExists = [
        ['Los Angeles', 'Chicago'],
        ['New York','Los Angeles'],
        ['New York','Chicacgo']
    ]


agreement = []

for a, b in itertools.combinations(orderExists, 2):
    if compareOrders(a, b):
        agreement.append(True)
    else: agreement.append(False)

if all(agreement): print('ORDER EXISTS')
else: print('ORDER VIOLATION')
```